# Yii Criteria with "with" yields duplicates

Tags: yii, unique, criteria, yii-components

This is my Criteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('userUrls');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->compare('userUrls.community_id',Yii::app()->params['currentCommunity']->id);
$criteria->order = 't.weight DESC, t.id DESC';
$urls = Url::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

I am basically trying to do a simple `JOIN` via a `MANY_MANY`. Except in the `JOIN` table I need an additional condition (that the community_id matched the given one).

Without `$criteria->together = true;` it fails in the WHERE statement.

If I add `$criteria->distinct = true;` it still gives me duplicates because other fields in the JOIN table make them technically 'UNIQUE'.

I want the results to be **UNIQUE** based on the URL fields, not the `userUrls` fields.

Comment: I think I found a very simple fix: `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `$criteria->group = 't.id';` fixed it all. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

try altering the join clause.

```
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN';
```

Comment: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_url` `userUrls` ON (`userUrls`.`url_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (' at line 1

Comment: I think it tried to JOIN twice with this: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`url` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`urlHash` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`language` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`title` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`summary` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`parent_id` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`views` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`mainImage` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`weight` AS `t0_c9`, `userUrls`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `userUrls`.`user_id` AS `t1_c1`, `userUrls`.`url_id` AS `t1_c2`, `userUrls`.`community_id` AS `t1_c3`, `userUrls`.`create_time` AS `t1_c4` FROM `url` `t` LEFT JOIN LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_url` `userUrls` ON (`userUrls`.`url_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (userUrls.community_id=:ycp0)

Comment: try adding the join and removing together.